# Cypress: how to upload huge file?

Tags: cypress

Is it possible to upload huge file using Cypress?
I test web ui of device and need to upload firmware package to install it on  device, check that device accepted file, proceed it, restarted device and all parts in ui react accordingly. Also it is necessary update firmware before all other tests to be sure new version works properly.

Cypress is 13.3.1, Node is 18.15

I tried following construct:

```
cy.readFile(`${uploadFolder}/${values.buildFileName}`, null, { timeout: 600000}).as('file');
cy.get('#sysinfoButtonFirmwareUpgrade').selectFile('@file');
```

or

```
cy.readFile(`${uploadFolder}/${values.buildFileName}`, null, { timeout: 600000}).then((content) => {
  expect(Cypress.Buffer.isBuffer(content)).to.be.true;
  cy.get('#sysinfoButtonFirmwareUpgrade').selectFile({
    contents: content,
    fileName: values.buildFileName,
    mimeType: 'application/x-tar',
  }, {force: true,  action: 'select'});});
```

or

```
cy.get('#sysinfoButtonFirmwareUpgrade').selectFile(fileName, {force: true,  action: 'select'});
```

All of them crashes Cypress with message

> Cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 characters
> Error: Cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 characters
> at Object.slice (node:buffer:655:37)
> at Buffer.toString (node:buffer:825:14)
> at a (:4457:67003)
> at s.exports (:4457:67130)
> at :4457:68422
> at Array.forEach ()
> at Object.encodePayload (:4457:68405)
> at :4515:21336
> at new Promise ()
> at a (:4515:21238)
> at p.emit (:4515:23252)
> at :4515:24486
> at :4515:48712

File is about 400MB length. This code works for files less then 100 MB
If I click on HTML  manually and select the same file - it uploaded without any errors. But I need to automate this.

I do not understand why Cypress tries interpret Buffer as string - see error text - `at Buffer.toString (node:buffer:825:14)`. In readFile() I using encoding type as null, means get content as binary array.

I expected to be enabled allow files at least 500MB-1BG sizes
How to workaround this? Any solution?